# If NULL Then 0 Else Other Value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query that comes out with null values and numbers in the Vet_Ben_Code column.
I want all the NULL to Read as 0 and all the other numbers to stay the same how do I do This. Here is the query:

```
SELECT STU.Term_Code,
    STU.PIDM,
    STU.Vet,
    RXR.Vet_Ben_Code

FROM
  (SELECT CST.Term_Code,
    CST.PIDM,
    SPB.Vet

  FROM
    (SELECT Term_Code,
      PIDM

     FROM CHELINK.Combined_Student_Table
     WHERE Term_Code BETWEEN '201170' AND '201670'
    )CST
  INNER JOIN
    (SELECT SPBPERS_PIDM,
      SPBPERS_VETC_FILE_NUMBER Vet

     FROM SATURN.SPBPERS
     WHERE SPBPERS_VETC_FILE_NUMBER LIKE 'Y%'
     OR SPBPERS_VETC_FILE_NUMBER LIKE 'y%'
    )SPB

  ON CST.PIDM = SPB.SPBPERS_PIDM
  )STU

LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT RXRVETN_Term_Code_VA AS Term_Code,
    RXRVETN_PIDM               AS PIDM,
    RXRVETN_Vetc_Code          AS Vet_Ben_Code

  FROM FAISMGR.RXRVETN
  WHERE RXRVETN_Term_Code_VA BETWEEN '201170' AND '201670'
  )RXR

ON STU.Term_Code    = RXR.Term_Code
AND STU. PIDM       = RXR.PIDM
```

Comment: NVL( RXR.Vet_Ben_Code,0)

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`NVL`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm):

```
NVL(col, 0)
```

or [`COALESCE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617):

```
COALESCE(col, 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use either `NVL()` or `COALESCE()`.

```
SELECT NVL(NULL, 0) from dual;
SELECT COALESCE(NULL, 0) from dual;
```

`NVL` will return either the non-null value or, if it is null then the second parameter.

`COALESCE` allows for multiple parameters and will evaluate to the first non-null value in the parameter list.

Comment: Not by design or scheme, and while mine may have ended up being similar to yours, I described the functions within my answer. I don't see the need to down-vote similar answers. Down-votes should normally be reserved for outright incorrect, or otherwise severely lacking answers. Not due to similarity. But whatever.

Answer (score 4):

If Oracle then use this:

```sql
SELECT NVL(NULL, 0) from dual;
```

If SQL the use this:

```sql
SELECT ISNULL(STU.Term_Code, 0) from dual;
```

Comment: Why not Standard SQL `COALESCE` instead of two proprietory functions? Both Oracle and SQL Server (which you probably mean by just *SQL*) and almost evry other DBMS support it.

Comment: Good point. !!!. If you look at the execution plans the plan for COALESCE is slightly more complex, most noticeably with an additional Stream Aggregate operator and a higher number of reads. If no complex things then might be COALESCE will be equal to ISNULL. [Check this link for more information](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull)

Comment: I know about the differences between `ISNULL` and `COALESCE` in SQL Server, but this query is not complex :-)

Comment: :) Agree that will be user's call then whether need to use Coalesce or isnull

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return some "other value", rather than the original value, use [NVL2()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/NVL2.html)

```
NVL2(col, 1, 0) -- returns 1 for NOT NULL, 0 for NULL
```